# Managing ESXi with salt-minion

Tags: linux, salt-stack, esxi

I want to install salt-minion on ESXi. But how do I manage ESXi bare metal OS using salt-stack?

Answer (score 0):

If you can ssh into it and it has python then you can use salt-ssh.

First enable sshd on esxi by following these or similar steps:
http://techhead.co/vsphere-5-x-how-to-enable-ssh-esxi-shell/

Then read up on Salt SSH:
http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/ssh/

Create a /etc/salt/roster file with the target's particulars:

```
targetMinion:
  host: 192.168.42.1 # The IP addr or DNS hostname
  user: fred         # Remote executions will be executed as user fred
  passwd: foobarbaz  # The password to use for login, if omitted, keys are used
  sudo: True         # Whether to sudo to root, not enabled by default
```

Give it a test:

```
$ sudo salt-ssh targetMinion test.versions_report
targetMinion:
               Salt: 2014.1.13
             Python: 2.6.8 (unknown, Jun  9 2012, 11:30:32)
             Jinja2: 2.3.1
           M2Crypto: Not Installed
     msgpack-python: 0.4.0
       msgpack-pure: Not Installed
           pycrypto: Not Installed
             PyYAML: 3.09
              PyZMQ: Not Installed
                ZMQ: Not Installed
```

( The above output is from a cygwin openssh install on a windows VM )